# Ввести два массива с клавиатуры, затем найти их сумму, затем найти минимальный элемент массива суммы

Tags: c++

Нужна программа для с++ запутался вот наработка

```
using namespace std;

const int Nmax = 100;

int main()
{
    double A[Nmax];
    int n;
    double max;
    int i_max;
    int i;
    cout << "Input size ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Input elements ";
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> A[i];
    max = A[0];
    i_max = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (A[i] < max)
        {
            max = A[i];
            i_max = i;
        }
    cout << "A[" << i_max << "] = " << max;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну а в чем проблема (кроме полного отсутствия форматирования)? Минимум вы уже нашли (хоть и назвали его максимумом), так что в вопросе немного да ориентируетесь...

Comment: мне нужно туда вставить массив и сложить его и чтобы сортировка работала